# Dynamically add meta-data to office365 page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, office365

I am developing an office365 site. There i have a page, i want to add meta tags (keywords) dynamically to that page.

We can't have code-behind. we can't use server side code. we can't access the page's header tag in sandbox solution, so sandbox fails here. We can't do it through javascript, that is not worth.

Any idea?

Comment: What you mean by metadata? The `<meta>` tags in the HTML header?

Comment: Oh, i misspelled. You are right <meta> tags

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Impossible. Office365 is not an environment where you could achieve 'advanced' alterations to the behavior of the base SharePoint platform.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your valuable information. you saved me from wasting the time to search the soln. I will handle it in another way...